# Problem with file_get_contents() and special characters

Tags: php, special-characters, file-get-contents

I was working with file_get_contents() with urls containing special characters. i picked some urls from wikipedia for checking.

my "test1.php"

```
    <?php
     header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
      echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
    ?>
```

urls i tested:(note: the special characters are not properly displayed in these links..click on the link to see the special char at the address bar)

http://localhost/te/test1.php?url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%A2i-l%C3%B4

---- THE ABOVE URL WORKED and display the contents but BELOW DOESN'T WORK ------

http://localhost/te/test1.php?url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pha%CC%8Dk-oa-chhi_romanization

localhost/te/test1.php?url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bb%C3%A1nl%C3%A1m_H%C5%8Dngggi%C3%A1n_P%C4%ABny%C4%ABn_H%C5%8Dng%C3%A0n

I tried mb_convert_encoding() but it didnt solve... Help me to solve this.Thanks in adv.

Comment: Note that if all you are doing is decoding the special characters without further validation, you are potentially opening the door for the user to specify an arbitrary file on the server, which is a huge security risk.

Comment: Just for testing purposes: I believe it will work OK if you create a form with textbox for this url. Of course you will need to paste percent encoded urls in this textbox as in your examples above.

Answer (score 2):

for that I believe you have to use . urlencode($variable);

Comment: In order to test with urlencode() , i have to modify my code or else it encodes  all (: , / , ?). my modified code is
 <?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$str=urlencode($_GET['title']);
echo file_get_contents('http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'.$str); ?> 
my tested urls are:   http://localhost/te/test1.php?title=Bb%C3%A1nl%C3%A1m_H%C5%8Dngggi%C3%A1n_P%C4%ABny%C4%ABn_H%C5%8Dng%C3%A0n   but still not working.anyway thanks Jeff.  Any ideas???